# Is the set of non decreasing functions a "planar cone"?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, convex-geometry, convex-cone

Let $C \subseteq H$ be a cone that contains the origin. This is a set that satisfices $v, w \in C$ then $v + w \in C$ and $\lambda v \in C$ if $\lambda \geq 0$.
I am insterested in two types of cones,

**"Planar Cones"**

$C \subseteq H$ is a cone and $$ C = \{\sum a_iv_i  + \sum b_i e_i, \, \quad a_i \geq 0, \, b_i \in \mathbb R\}$$ where $v_1, e_1, v_2, e_2, \ldots$ are lineraly independent.

**Finitely Planar Cones**

C is a cone and  $D = C \cap S$  is a Planar Cone  for any $S \subseteq H$ **finite** dimentional subspace.

Does the set of non decreasing functions over an interval hold any of these properties?

Comment: You're interested in the set of *monotonic* functions or *increasing functions*?  The sum of an increasing function and a decreasing function may not be monotonic.

Comment: Edited. Thanks.